# What is PointForm?

Tags: graphics, functions, graphics3d

I stumbled across a function called `PointForm` but the only documentation I can find is the pop-up line offered by autocomplete, which contains the same information as `Information[PointForm]`:

[image]

What does this mean and how does it work?

Comment: `Graphics3D[{PointForm[Sphere[]], Point[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}}]}]` gives "PointForm is not a 3D graphics primitive or directive".  Also, apparently [it has been there at least since version 7](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Jun/msg00317.html).

Comment: Hum, quite a number of symbols reported by `?*Form` are internal. I bet they are generated internally by built-ins for the front-end.

Comment: @Szabolcs It has been there as early as 1994. See [this  posting](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/sci.math.symbolic/AP2kJOkyUu8/dSzPbli6do4J)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to use `PointForm`; however, if you want spheres for points:

```
pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {2.5, 2.5, 2.5}, {5, 5, 5}};

Graphics3D[Sphere[pts, .3]]
```

or

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[#, .3] & /@ pts]
```

Comment: Or `Graphics3D[Translate[Sphere[], pts]]` which readily generalizes to other shapes than spheres.